# Set time with "Date -s" return "invalid date"

Tags: debian, date, arm

My system is Debian 8 (armv7l, a 32-bit processor). I can not understand why two script below are the same format but the second one return error.

```
root@abcxyz:~# date -s "2037-1-20"
Tue Jan 20 00:00:00 JST 2037
root@abcxyz:~# date -s "2047-1-20"
date: invalid date '2047-1-20'
```

Comment: 32-bit system? Or perhaps Debian 8 is old enough that the patches adding 64-bit date support aren't in it. (Works fine on Ubuntu 16.04, by the way)

Comment: We have yet to send John Titor back in time.

Comment: Yes, I work with 32-bit system. Thank you all!